# Looking for a specific female maths writer, who has written on infinity

Tags: reference-books, infinity

I once read a book on infinity that was written by an American female maths writer. Her writing was very easy to read and she was a great explainer of concepts. A very distinct aspect of her books was that there were only a few words on each line to assist with reading quickly. (For these reasons, I think the author and her works would be of interest to folks reading this site. Once this question has been accurately answered, I encourage you to check out her books.)

Can anyone tell me her name?

Comment: Only the first line in your question annoys me; after all, you don't "have to" ask.  I'd delete that; the rest looks fine!

Comment: Is this really on topic? How is this about teaching mathematics?

Comment: "She was very easy to read and a great explainer of concepts." - I assumed the book was of interest because of its approach, not just the subject matter.

Comment: @JPBurke: That's fair, but was not totally clear. I added a parenthetical to make it obvious.

Answer (score 10):

Lillian R. Lieber

Author of [Infinity: Beyond the Beyond the Beyond](http://books.google.com/books?id=AhI1Uea_Pb8C&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3a%22Lillian%20R.%20Lieber%22&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: For more books by her, see my recent math StackExchange answer at [Dr Seuss style prose advanced mathematics text](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712540/dr-seuss-style-prose-advanced-mathematics-text).

Comment: I vividly recall reading "The Education of T.C. Mits" as a kid. One of the most inspirational books I saw at the time. Made mathematics _real_, not a school subject.